# VBA Array Index Match

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I've been trying to run an array formula to return a variable.

On column B I have dates & times (mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm) and column C I have temperatures. I want to look for a value greater than or equal to 215 on the temperature column "C".

```
Dim TEMP215 As Variant
With Application.WorksheetFunction
TEMP215 = .Index(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C2:C460"), .Match(True, ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C2:C460") >= 215, 0))
End With
```

If I write the formula just like that in a cell it works perfectly, running it with Ctrl + Shift + Enter. I have tried the TEMP215 as variant, long, integer, double, single... pretty much everything without success...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Evaluate method...

```
Dim TEMP215 As Variant

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C2:C460")
    TEMP215 = Evaluate("INDEX(" & .Address(External:=True) & ",MATCH(TRUE," & .Address(External:=True) & ">=215,0))")
End With
```

Note that the Evaluate method has a 255 character limit.

Comment: How about when I have 2 different ranges? Now I want to find the value and return the time from column B
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
    TIME235 = .Index(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("$B$25:$B$" & LastRow), .Match(TEMP235, ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("$" & TCColLet & "$25:$" & TCColLet & "$" & LastRow), 0))
    End With

Comment: The previous one worked like charm BTW, thank you very much mate!

Comment: It looks like your lookup value for Match is incorrect.  Shouldn't it be  `.Match(TEMP215, ...`?